# Unreachable Statement - Why here?

Tags: java

I have the following code and I am getting an unreachable statement error being thrown up. The line in question has a comment after it saying that it is the culprit.

```
public static void selectPlayer ()
{
    // Loops through Player class' static array. If an index is storing a player object then print the player name out with a number for selection.
    for(int i=0; 1<101; i++)
    {
        if (Player.playerArray[i] != null)
        {
            System.out.println(i + ". " + Player.playerArray[i - 1].playerName);
        }

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the number that corresponds to the player you wish to use; "); // This line is where it failed to compile a la unreachable statement.
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Take players selection and minus 1 so that it matches the Array index the player should come from.
        int menuPlayerSelection = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        // Offer to play a new game with selected player, view player's stats, or exit.
        System.out.print("You have selected " + Player.playerArray[menuPlayerSelection].playerName + ".\n1) Play\n2) View Score\n3) Exit?\nWhat do you want to do?: ");
        int areYouSure = scanner.nextInt();
        // Check player's selection and run the corresponding method/menu
        switch (areYouSure)
        {
            case 1: MainClass.playGame(menuPlayerSelection); break;
            case 2: MainClass.viewPlayerScore(menuPlayerSelection); break;
            case 3: MainClass.firstMenu(); break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid selection, please try again.\n");
                         MainClass.firstMenu();
        }
    }
```

My question is, how do I fix it? I get why unreachable statement errors usually occur but I can't figure out why it's happening in my case.

Comment: This coding style is the next logical step after the inline `{`.  why not use an inline `}`

Comment: One closing bracket is missing (}), but maybe its just stackoverflow's editor...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First edit this.

```
for(int i=0; 1<101; i++) {
```

It is infinte loop.

So set i instead of 1.

```
for(int i=0; i<101; i++){
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Looks like it's difficult to see the difference between the i and the 1 with the font I have. Cheers, much appreciated.

Comment: @RudiKershaw You have forgot to close the for loop bracket also.

Comment: While true, this doesn't explain why the line in question is considered unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the condition of  your for-loop.  It will never end.

Comment: But 1 is always less than 101 so the condition always true -> infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; 1<101; i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=0; i<101; i++)
```

Your condition is 1<101 . It will be always true which is infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

your code is missing a `}`  that would certainly cause it to break

and as others have said, your for loop

```
for(int i=0; 1<101; i++)
```

will always meet it's condition, and it looks like you'll start getting `IndexOutOfBound` exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you have `for(int i=0; 1<101; i++)` which is an infinite loop (because 1 is allways lower than 101).